# When a boost::shared_ptr might not be freed?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

Afer reading this topic
[C++ interview preparation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569778/c-interview-preparation)
(Matt's answer) I've got a question about boost::shared_ptr. Is it really possible for shared_ptr to leak memory? How?

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826902/how-to-avoid-memory-leak-with-boostshared-ptr

Comment: `new boost::shared_ptr<T>(new T()); // o noez!`

Comment: @James McNellis: nice example :-D

Comment: `{ boost::shared_ptr<T> sp(new T()); std::exit(0); } // o noez!`

Comment: `{ boost::shared_ptr<T> sp(new T()); std::terminate(); }` :)

Comment: `void f(std::shared_ptr<T>, int);` called as `f(std::shared_ptr<T>(new T()), (throw 0, 0)); // maybe o noez... maybe not`

Comment: I don't think it should count as a leak if the only reason it leaked was because someone called `exit`, *unless* the leak is visible outside the program (e.g. some state in the filesystem didn't get cleaned up).  Not bothering to tear down memory-only data structures can be the difference between a speedy exit and the user twiddling their thumbs for long enough to get irritated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr` uses reference counts, and that means circular references can cause leaks.  Concretely:

```
struct A {
    shared_ptr<A> other;
};

shared_ptr<A> foo() {
    shared_ptr<A> one(new A);
    shared_ptr<A> two(new A);
    one->other = two;
    two->other = one;
    return one;
}
```

the data structure returned by `foo` will never be deallocated without manual intervention (set either of the `other` pointers to NULL).

Now this is just a fact that every programmer should know; the more interesting interview conversation is what to do about it.  Options include:

- redesigning the data structure so pointer cycles are not necessary;
- demoting at least one pointer in every cycle to a non-owning reference (a bare pointer or a [`weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm));
- a dedicated [cycle collector](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=cycle+collection);
- as a last resort, manually NULLing out pointers at appropriate points (this breaks exception safety).

Comment: Thank you! Never had such situation, that looks quite strange, it's better to avoid cycles.

Comment: It does make life easier to avoid cycles, but sometimes they are necessary, and sometimes avoiding them is way more work than dealing with them.

Comment: Yes, but that's a rare situation, and situation, where cycles need to use shared_ptr are rare even more. Weak_ptr looks like a good solution to that, however it would be interesting to read about dedicated cycle collectors.

Answer (score 1):

Circular references; a common problem in reference counting garbage collectors.

I suggest you read the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/boostsmartptr.aspx#Cyclic References

Answer (score 0):

shared_ptr is a reference counting mechanism.  One gotcha with ref counting is you can have a circular chain of references no one else refers to.  You chain will never get freed unless there's a mechanism to 'break the chain'.